# Calculator program that I just created in c++ does only addition! Whats wrong with my code?

Tags: c++, calculator

I made a calculator program in c++ (after seeing a model in learncpp.com {section 1.10a})

It was created to add, sub, multiply, divide...

But it always adds the given two numbers.

It compiles fine but only adds! Even if I chose any number during operator selection (ie, 1 for add, 2 for sub etc.,), like 2,3 or even 25 or 2678, It just adds the two given numbers...(It can add only if i selected 1 right?)

I've spent hours trying to resolve but I'm just too new to c++ I don't know how!

Please help guys...

Heres my program

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int GetNo()
{
    std::cout << "Enter your Number: ";
    int a;
    std::cin >> a;
    return a;
}

int GetOp()
{
    std::cout << "Your Operator?" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  (1 = +)" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  (2 = -)" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  (3 = *)" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  (4 = /)" << std::endl;
    int o;
    std::cin >> o;
    return o;
}

int Calc(int x, int op, int y)
{
    if (op == 1);
        return x + y;
    if (op == 2);
        return x-y;
    if (op == 3);
        return x*y;
    if (op == 4);
        return x/y;

        return -1;

}

void PRINT(int q)
{
    std::cout << "Therefore, Your Result is, " << q << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int x = GetNo();
    int opr = GetOp();
    int y = GetNo();
    int q = Calc(x,opr,y);
    PRINT(q);
}
```

TQ guys! I'm waiting for helpful replies...
And if possible, Be more elaborate...(cuz im new to cpp)

Comment: Why Are You Using Numbers Instead Of The Characters Themselves?

Comment: `if (op == 1);` => `if (op == 1)` without `;`. Everywhere.

Comment: What were the results when you used a debugger to single step through the code?

Comment: removing ";" worked!

Comment: Btw this is another good example why you should compile with a high warning level: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ff96abd4596370e

Comment: Not sure why close vote. The question has code, expected behavior (subtract/divide/multiply) and actual behavior (always add). A debugger doesn't help in this case, as that just shows the actual behavior is the actual behavior, namely addition. `return x+y` is always executed. The debugger can't show you _why_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you put a ; after an if clause it means that the if is an empty block.Therefore whether the statement is true or false the statement next to if is always excecuted.So your code

```
   if (op == 1);
    return x + y;
```

evaluates to :

```
  if (op == 1)
      {            //empty block
      }
  return x + y; // Outside if statement
```

Therefore always addition is returned.

Answer (score 3):

```
    if (op == 1);//this semicolon makes the statement end here so it tests the condition and ends the statement 
    return x + y;//so this is an independent statement and will always be executed
```

So remove the semicolon at the end of all `if(condition)` statements

Answer (score 0):

Your code has the following:

int Calc(int x, int op, int y)
   {
       if (op == 1);
           return x + y;
       if (op == 2);
           return x-y;
       if (op == 3);

the problem is the ; after `if (op == 1);`. This is being evaluated and nothing is happening, then you are always performing `return x + y;`.

A better way to do loops is to always include the brackets so that these simple mistakes are less common, such as:

if (op==1) 
   {
     return x + y;
   }

Answer (score 0):

Your Mistake Is In The `calc()`Function.Take A Look:

```
int Calc(int x, int op, int y)
{
if (op == 1);  //the ; is not needed, remove it! 
    return x + y;
//same happens with the rest of the conditions, remove all semicolons after the if conditions 
//...
}
```